# Rails - Turn 2-dimensional array into list and back

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an array like this:

```
[["09:00",4,15],["09:00",4,15]]
```

And I want to output this in a text area like this:

```
"09:00",4,15
"09:00",4,15
```

The user can edit it and then I want to convert it back into an array with sub-arrays.

For the first step I could do an `each` and remove the `[]` with `gsub` but this does not seem to be the best way. And then to turn it back into an array I would need even more code.

It's kind of a CSV output but I am not working with any files here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given

```
arr = [["09:00",4,15],["09:00",4,15]]
```

You can use the CSV module from the standard library:

```
require 'csv'

lines = CSV.generate {|csv| arr.each(&csv.method(:<<))}
# => "09:00,4,15\n09:00,4,15\n"

CSV.parse(lines, converters: :integer)
# => [["09:00", 4, 15], ["09:00", 4, 15]]
```

Answer (score 3):

To produce the output, something like this could work:

```
input = [["09:00",4,15],["09:00",4,15]]

output = input
  .map { |list| list.join(",") }
  .join("\n")

puts output
```

which prints:

```
09:00,4,15
09:00,4,15
```

Then you can turn it back into the input using `split`:

```
result = output
  .split("\n")
  .map { |line| line.split(",") }
# => [["09:00", "4", "15"], ["09:00", "4", "15"]]
```

The problem, as you maybe noticed, is that the numbers are transformed into strings. This is because when you print something to the page, you are inevitably turning it into a string, and Ruby can't *just know* that it's supposed to be a number.

You could, if you wanted, turn the second and third elements to numbers:

```
result2 = result.map do |(time, num1, num2)|
  [time, num1.to_i, num2.to_i]
end
```